# How to get a digit over curved arrow pointing left and right?

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrow-curve

I want to get like this : 
 [image]

I have tried with these following code but it does not give my expected result.

```
$\stackon{0}{\scriptstyle\curvearrowleft}~ 
 \stackon[2pt]{1}{\scriptstyle\curvearrowleft}~
 \stackon[1pt]{0}{\scriptstyle\curvearrowleft}$
```

How can I get my required result?

**Added:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for '\curvearrowleft' macro
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\overset' macro
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\begin{document}

$\stackon{0}{\scriptstyle\curvearrowleft}~ 
\stackon[2pt]{1}{\scriptstyle\curvearrowleft}~
\stackon[1pt]{0}{\scriptstyle\curvearrowleft}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried exchanging the arguments of `\stackon` like `\stackon[1pt]{\scriptstyle\curvearrowleft}{0}`?

Comment: @Skillmon I have done it with tikz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a TikZ `matrix of math nodes`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
matrix of math nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
row sep=4pt,
column sep=4pt,
] (mymatr) {
1& 0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1& 0& 1\\
&+&1& 0& 1&0& 1& 0& 1\\
1& 0 &1 &0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1\\
};
\draw ([yshift=-2pt]mymatr-2-1.south west) -- ([yshift=-2pt]mymatr-2-9.south east);
\draw[-Latex] (mymatr-1-4.north)  to[in=90, out=90, looseness=2]  node[midway, above, font=\footnotesize]{$1$} (mymatr-1-3.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the partial solution of my problem with tikz. Alternative solution will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,trim left=0pt, trim right=0pt]

\draw (3.3,4) node {1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1};
\draw (3.25,3.6) node {\quad+\,1 0 1 0 1 0 1 };

\draw (1.8,3.35)-- (4.8,3.35);

\draw (3.3,3.1) node {1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1};


\draw [ -latex] (3.07,4.3) to [bend right] (2.7,4.3);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw (2.93,4.55) node {$1$};
\end{scriptsize}




\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]