# Drawing simple overhead arrow

Tags: arrow-curve

I am planning to draw an arrow over the digits like in the figures:

[image] [image]

So far I tried `$\overset{\curvearrowleft}{5}$`, but It didn't produce arrows as the figures. I also tried this:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    row sep=4pt,
    column sep=4pt,
    ] (mymatr) {
    1& 0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1& 0& 1\\
    &+&1& 0& 1&0& 1& 0& 1\\
    1& 0 &1 &0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1\\
    };
    \draw ([yshift=-2pt]mymatr-2-1.south west) -- ([yshift=-2pt]mymatr-2-9.south east);
    \draw[-Latex] (mymatr-1-4.north)  to[in=90, out=90, looseness=2]  node[midway, above, font=\footnotesize]{$1$} (mymatr-1-3.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This code is burden for whole document. It should be independent of any other nodes/elements of tikz (without `mymatr-1-4.north` etc.).

I need a single line and short solution to draw the arrow as I have lots of places where the arrows will be drawn in the whole document. That's why I want make it *simple, easy to use, inline and also parametric* (as you see in the second figure, the number may contain multiple digits).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439929/how-to-get-a-digit-over-curved-arrow-pointing-left-and-right/440088#440088

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

[image: screenshoot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
   
%definition of arrow (fleche in fernch) 
\newcommand{\fleche}[3]{
\draw[-{Latex[flex]}] (#1.north) .. controls ++(0,.25) and ++(0,.25) .. node[midway, above, font=\footnotesize]{$#3$} (#2.north);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    row sep=4pt,
    column sep=4pt,
    ] (mymatr) {
    1& 0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1& 0& 1\\
    &+&1& 0& 1&0& 1& 0& 1\\
    1& 0 &1 &0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1\\
    };
    \draw ([yshift=-2pt]mymatr-2-1.south west) -- ([yshift=-2pt]mymatr-2-9.south east);
    %------
    % arrows 
    \fleche{mymatr-1-4}{mymatr-1-3}{$1$}
    \fleche{mymatr-1-5}{mymatr-1-6}{$2$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Old answer

Like this?
the code is commented

[image: screenshoot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta,bending}%<- add bending library
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    row sep=4pt,
    column sep=4pt,
    ] (mymatr) {
    1& 0 &1 &0 &1 &0 &1& 0& 1\\
    &+&1& 0& 1&0& 1& 0& 1\\
    1& 0 &1 &0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1\\
    };
    \draw ([yshift=-2pt]mymatr-2-1.south west) -- ([yshift=-2pt]mymatr-2-9.south east);
    %-------------
    % add flex option, in= 60, out=120, looseness=1
    \draw[-{Latex[flex]}] (mymatr-1-4.north)  to[in=60, out=120, looseness=1,]  node[midway, above, font=\footnotesize]{$1$} (mymatr-1-3.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want something more shorter the the code provided. In-line code.

Comment: It should independent of any other nodes/elements of tikz (without `mymatr-1-4.north` etc.).

Comment: You want a macro ?

Comment: Yes, it will the best. Single parametric macro, where the number should be the param.

Comment: Will the arrow always go from one cell to its neighbor horizontally?

Comment: Yes, they only indicates horizontal direction, left or right.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Are you ok with macro `\fleche`?

Comment: Can you add a bit explanations of parameters or how ot works. It will be helpful for me.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my answer tonight or tomorrow with the explanations because I have to go out walking my dog...

Comment: Sure. One more point. Actually I will use it with regular numbers, not with tikz elements. as I will not have anything like `*.north`. Example of use: 27 \fleche{5}3 \fleche{2}4 for the number 275324. I want the output that shown in the figure of the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131645/discussion-between-andrec-and-mmr).